# JWT verify returns null whle console log prints token just fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

So perhaps someone can tell me why this is happening. I am trying to verify a JWT and when I try and pass the token through a function I always get invalid token and my decode sais that it is null. However when I console log the token it shows up just fine, and if I pass a variable with the token hard coded it verifies the token without issue. I am guessing its some BS async not syncing with the function, but I can't get anything to work and every online resource is pretty much showing me the same thing I have here.

```
// Verify Token

function verifyToken(req, res, next) {

console.log("Verifying Token")

// Get auth header value

let bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];

// Check if bearer is undefied

// console.log("header:", bearerHeader)

if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {

// Split at the space

let bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');

// Get toekn from array

let bearerToken = bearer[1];

// set the token

req.token = bearerToken;

// Next middleware

console.log("token being passed:", req.token) //this prints the token just fine

setTimeout(function () { console.log("JWT:", jwt.decode(req.token, { complete: true })); }, 3000);

// For some reason the jwt.verify runs before it has the JWT and fails as an invalid token of null.

jwt.verify(req.token, options.key, (err, authData) => {

if (err) {

console.log('token error:', err)

res.sendStatus(403);

} else {

next();

}

})

} else {

// Forbidden

console.log('Not Authorized')

res.sendStatus(403);

}

};
```

Comment: Just because the output looks like a JWT token doesn't mean it's properly encoded. If you take the token that gets logged and put it into https://jwt.io to decode, what is the result? Does it look right and have no errors? (Looking at the source code of the JsonWebToken / JWS libraries, it looks like it will return null only if the supplied token is not a valid token.)

Comment: Also, why are you decoding 3 seconds after verifying?